# Android How to send edittext's text to textview's text at the same time?

Tags: android, append

Basically, I want to get chars from `EditText`s and append `TextView`s text. For example, when I'm writing hello, `TextView`s text changed in a process:

1. h
2. he
3. hel
4. hell
5. hello

So how can I do that? I tried `addTextChangedListener()` but I have some errors. Maybe another method from you helps me.

Comment: If you have some errors, please post the logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a listener to your edittext to listen for changes:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher{

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        // This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, 
        // the text has been changed.   
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        // This method is called to notify you that, within s, 
        // the count characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by 
        // new text with length after.
    } 

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        // This method is called to notify you that, within s, 
        // the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old 
        // text that had length before.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put your edittext data to textview then you have to sync you edittext field simultaneously and  this can be done by using a thread. bellow the code the instance of Handler is associated with a single thread.You can sync your background as per your defined time interval by changing the second argument value of postDelayed method

```
    Tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);


    final Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Tv.setText(Et.getText().toString());
        handler.postDelayed(this,100);
        }
    },100);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OnKeyListenr.

So you have to set a Listener in your editText:

```
myedittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
                 //Here you update your textView
                 key = KeyCharacterMap.load(KeyCharacterMap.BUILT_IN_KEYBOARD);
                 myTv.append(key.getDisplayLabel(keyCode)();
                 return true;
            }
});
```

I hope this help you.
Bye :)

Comment: This wont work if user moves the cursor or copy/pastes the text.

Comment: yep. onTextChange is much more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        finalTextView.setText(editText.getText());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The ticked answer is wrong...

```
entertxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher () {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
                // This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s,
                // the text has been changed.
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
                // This method is called to notify you that, within s,
                // the count characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by
                // new text with length after.
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                // This method is called to notify you that, within s,
                // the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old
                // text that had length before.
            }
        });
```

Comment: Wrong in what way? This isn't supposed to be a game of spot the difference.

Comment: Answer forget to add brackets before "new TextWatcher", so the code given by you was not working.